# Applying font styles to elements inside CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to apply a font style or any other style to an element inside CSS?

For instance

You defined a certain font style

```
.impact {       
    font-family: "Impact"; 
    letter-spacing: 16px;  
    line-height: 72%;
}
```

Now apply this style to an element inside css:

```
#certainElement {
     font-family: Impact (the one we defined)
     width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Sorry, did not completely understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, CSS does not support this kind of composition. However, you can use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) to get similar behavior.

Is there any reason that defining a class on your element with id `certainElement` isn't desirable?

```
<div id="certainElement" class="impact"></div>
```

Comment: What wrong with having a certain class for the font style and applying that class in your HTML?

Comment: Well if you had 100 elements and you had to change them, that would be a pain wouldn't it?

Comment: No one ever said CSS was bliss! The key is to choose a class name that is descriptive enough to be informative while reading code but not so long that the markup becomes a mess. It's a tricky balance.

Comment: My main problem is you have a big long definition, like the one above, and copying and pasting this every time you have to add a new element to your page.

Comment: You don't have to copy/paste the definition. Make sure all of your pages reference the CSS file that defines `.impact` and then all you need to do is include `class="impact"` on any element on which you wish to apply the styles. Basically, it looks like you need to read up on HTML's `class` attribute.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. However if you decide for instance that all radio buttons, or all divs on a certain part of your page are now going to have a certain font style. You either have to go manually and add these classes to each element, or go into the stylesheet and add the big lengthy definition from the font definitions. Seems kind of redundant, and probably can only be solved with frameworks.

Comment: It really depends on your exact markup. If you want to apply specific styles to a range of elements within a single parent element, use something like `#parentElement div`, `.parentElement *` etc.